# Why won't transitions work?

Tags: jquery, iphone, html, css, jquery-mobile

Im making a website with jQuery Mobile, HTML and CSS and Id like to apply cool transitions when I navigate between between pages. I use a navbar with three buttons but I can't get the transitions to work. It looks the same however I do it. Anyone know whats wrong?

I put `data-transition="slide"` in the data-roles.

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-mini="true" id="change" data-transition="slide"></a>
```

Comment: We're going to need to see some code

Comment: <a href="http://www.officefactory.se/" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-mini="true" id="change" data-transition="slide">WEBB<br />VERSION</a>

Comment: Please put your code in your question. Also, that's not really enough to see what your issue is.

Comment: Well thats all I have. That is all the code that says to be needed for the transitions. Or do you want me to post all of my html code?

Comment: Do you have your nav bar inside a table?  Transitions aren't very reliable in table elements.

Comment: Yeah I do. Maybe its that then.

Answer (score 0):

**1)** You can't link to external domains. For the transitions to work, the pages have to be hosted on the same domain because jQuery Mobile uses AJAX to load pages before transitioning to them and AJAX is restricted by [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Policies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control). So make sure you're trying to link to a page that isn't external.

**2)** If that is all the code you're using then you need more structure to your jQuery Mobile pseudo-pages. This is an example from the [jQuery Mobile documentation for Page Anatomy](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
    <title>Page Title</title> 

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body> 

<div data-role="page" id="page1">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Page Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">   
        <p><a href="#page2" data-role="button" data-theme="c" data-mini="true" id="change" data-transition="slide">I'ma Button</a></p>      
    </div><!-- /content -->

    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Page Footer</h4>
    </div><!-- /footer -->
</div><!-- /page -->

</body>
</html>
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zaaeM/

Comment: Well ofcourse I have more code than that but I showed only it because I didnt think the rest mattered. 
The rest of the code is the rest of the page. Divs, body, head and so on. and from what I can see at the example my code for the transition is the same so I still dont see why it wont work.

Comment: But the guy above said it could be if I had a navbar in the header, which I do.

Comment: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.1/docs/pages/page-transitions.html. I suggest thoroughly reading the documentation for page transitions (they disable themselves if necessary). If you're developing in a legacy browser then you won't get transitions (if this is the case... upgrade your browser). I can confirm that the JSFiddle I created works with slide transitions (Chrome browser): http://jsfiddle.net/zaaeM/